# How do you write out mathematical formulae in a thesis

Tags: thesis

I am writing out my thesis at the moment and I am using Machine Learning Algorithms. Let's say I am using Support Vector Machine. I am not necessarily re-inventing the algorithm nor am I implementing it in Python from scratch because I am using Scikit Learn. Then do you need to add the formulae in your thesis or do you just reference you used the package and used those hyperparameters?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: This should be the question for your thesis advisor.

Comment: I agree with @Nobody. I could tell you how I am writing in my thesis, but it wouldn't help much since your advisor may disagree with it (especially cause I changed some of my references/explanation since my supervisor told me to, so it's not even my "original" way)